# Are there templates in the C programming language?

Tags: c, templates

I am writing a linked list implementation in C, and would like to use a language feature equivalent to C++'s *templates* to make my work easier.

Does such a feature exist?

Comment: What do you mean by "template" in this context ?

Comment: Templates are a feature of the C++ programming language that allow functions and classes to operate with generic types.

Answer (score 7):

C has no templates like C++, though you can achieve something similar with "clever" (or WTFey, depending on how you look at it) use of `#define` macros.

However, take a look at how for example GLib does it for [singly linked lists](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html) or [doubly linked lists](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html).

Comment: Update as of 2021-03-06, the "singly linked lists" link results in "404 not found". However, at this time the "doubly linked lists" link does still work.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks mate.

Comment: looks like since then the links have been corrected

Answer (score 5):

Templates are features of C++, but if you want a type-independent implementation of singly- or doubly-linked list, it can be made with help of macros, or you can simply store a `void*` pointers in your structure.

Of course, there are lots of such implementations on the  Internet. [@MohamedKALLEL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14746465/693538) and [@hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14746493/693538) already gave an examples from Linux kernel and from GLib, I would like just to add a note about nice little library [**uthash**](http://troydhanson.github.com/uthash/).

It implements a hash table in C, but it also has an [**utlist.h**](http://troydhanson.github.com/uthash/utlist.html) that implements singly- and doubly-linked (and even circular) lists *entirely* on macros. That is, you can simply take this file, include it and either use these macros as is, or modify it for your needs. Also nice is that you can use any of your datastructures with it: it only need to have `next` pointer (and `prev`, in case of doubly-linked).

*P.s. But always remember when using macros: **with great power comes great responsibility**. Macros are powerful, but may become extremely unsafe and unreadable. Beware!*

Answer (score 4):

If you use `make` to build your software, one approach you may be able to use to achieve a similar result is to let make generate your code based on a template that you write, by calling something like sed or awk. I have used this approach many times and while it lacks the flexibility and features that C++ templates offer, it is extremely transparent (unlike macros), builds very efficiently, and requires no added tools apart from tried-and-true old-school unix utilities (e.g. `make` and `sed`). The main drawback is that you will specify your find/replace strings in a different location (a line in the *Makefile*) than your code.

Note that often, you would be better served by using function pointers and void pointers to just write a single code base that is versatile. However, if you want the additional performance from eliminating unnecessary function calls e.g. in tight loops, templates may be better and can be emulated as follows:

1. Write your template code, using placeholder names, with a template name such as *code.template.c*
2. Write your non-template code using function calls to your template code, after substituting in the appropriate names e.g. `my_int_func()` or `my_string_func()`
3. Possibly, use an #include to include your template code in your non-template code (e.g. if your template will have `inline` functions)
4. Write your Makefile to:

   - Generate the "real" C files from the template.c files. You will have one Makefile entry per template target e.g. *code.generated.c*. `sed` is a good substitution tool, but you could also use e.g. `replace` or `awk` or any of their Windows equivalents
   - As appropriate, compile the generated C files and link the generated objects

---

For example:

*code.template.c*

```
/* Makefile will call sed to replace DATANAME, DATATYPE and SPECIFIER */
void print_DATANAME_data(DATATYPE x) {
  printf("%SPECIFIER\n", x);
}
```

*code.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "printfuncs.generated.c"

int main() {
  int i = 99;
  print_int_data(99);

  char *s = "hello";
  print_str_data(s);

  float f = 1.234;
  print_float_data(f);
}
```

*Makefile*

```
all: my_program

my_program: code.c
    CC -o $@ code.c

code.c: printfuncs.generated.c

printfuncs.generated.c: code.template.c
    rm -f printfuncs.generated.c
    cat code.template.c | sed 's/DATANAME/int/g;s/DATATYPE/int/g;s/SPECIFIER/i/g;' >> printfuncs.generated.c
    cat code.template.c | sed 's/DATANAME/str/g;s/DATATYPE/char */g;s/SPECIFIER/s/g;' >> printfuncs.generated.c
    cat code.template.c | sed 's/DATANAME/float/g;s/DATATYPE/float/g;s/SPECIFIER/f/g;' >> printfuncs.generated.c
```

**build**

```
make
```

This will generate printfuncs.generated.c (if that file doesn't exist or is less recently modified than code.template.c), which will look like:

```
/* Makefile will call sed to replace int, int and i */
void print_int_data(int x) {
  printf("%i", x);
}
/* Makefile will call sed to replace str, char * and s */
void print_str_data(char * x) {
  printf("%s", x);
}
/* Makefile will call sed to replace float, float and f */
void print_float_data(float x) {
  printf("%f", x);
}
```

Any compiler errors will point to this file, and you can either directly tinker with this file to get it to compile (after which you'll need to update your template to prevent your changes from being lost), or edit the template. In either case, after your edits, all you need to do is run `make` to (try to) compile again.

**run**

`./my_program` (or `my_program.exe` if building on win)

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is [list.h](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/list.h). And it's a circular linked list:

the following link contains an [example](http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) of how to use it.

the `list.h` contains all functions related to the management of a circular linked list like definition, add in the head , add in the tail , remove, foreach function to browse the circular linked list...

Comment: This is an answer specific to the Linux kernel, it's not a general answer about how it is "in C". I find it odd that it's been voted up.

Comment: @unwind: I know that list.h is used in the kernel linux. but in the link I give in this answer for list.h is another distribution of list.h and it works in the userspace of linux and it's portable. I use it in all my user space application I develop and it works fine.

Comment: @unwind Refer to this paragraph in the link I give in the answer as example http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/ `With very little modifications (removing hardware prefetching of list items) we can also use this list in our applications. A usable version of this file is available here for download.`

Comment: @unwind Please Next time do not make judge before verifying

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: The quote doesn't address unwind's comment in any way at all.

Answer (score 1):

hi i don't know about linked lists but for a template function u can probably use a macro or a function with varying number of arguments as an example this program

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define INT 0
#define STR 1
void foo( int type, ... )
{
    va_list ap;
    int i;
    char *s;
    va_start( ap, type );
    switch( type ) {
    case INT:
        i = va_arg( ap, int );
        printf( "INT: %i\n", i );
        break;
    case STR:
        s = va_arg( ap, char * );
        printf( "STR: %s\n", s );
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    va_end( ap );
}
#define SWAP( type, a, b ) {                    \
        type t;                                 \
        t = a;                                  \
        a = b;                                  \
        b = t;                                  \
    }
int main( void )
{
    foo( INT, 3 );
    foo( STR, "baz" );
    int ia = 0, ib = 3;
    SWAP( int, ia, ib );
    printf( "%i %i\n", ia, ib );
    float fa = 0.5, fb = 3.14;
    SWAP( float, fa, fb );
    printf( "%f %f\n", fa, fb );
    return 0;
}
```

will produce the output

```
INT: 3
STR: baz
3 0
3.140000 0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-templates-and-generics-in-c-968da223154d).

C does not have static templates, but you can use macros to emulate them.

#### simplest form of a static template, a definition macro:

```c
// define a macro 
#define DEF(type, name, val) type name = val 
// call the macro 
DEF(int, foo, 5); 
// print the called macro 
printf("%d", foo);
```

"This template allows the code needed to define variables with basic type to be generalized and abstracted. The goal is to make code sharable and similar between types. However, this example is trivial in the sense it provides very little simplification over just writing out the statement. The real power comes from code that performs more complex tasks."

#### Here is a cut and paste example you can try out

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
#define FOREACH(type, start, end, fn)                                    \
    for (type _foreach_var = start; _foreach_var != end; _foreach_var++) \
    {                                                                    \
        fn(_foreach_var);                                                \
    }

#define PRINT_INT(n) printf("%d\n", n)
    // use FOREACH
    FOREACH(int, 0, 5, PRINT_INT)
}
```

- First we define our FOREACH macro.
- Then we can use it to loop such as here: `FOREACH(int, 0, 5, PRINT_INT)`